# Could not get the fontStyle property in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am creating a web application where I am creating a font property like this :

```
    var text = document.createElement('font');
    text.id = "jsFonts";
    text.style.fontStyle = fontStyle; // like "bold"
    text.style.fontName = fontName;  // arial
    text.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'pt'; 
    text.innerText = txt;
```

This works well in IE9 and above and also in chrome and firefox.
But In IE8 I am getting error like this :

```
Error: Could not get the fontStyle property. Invalid argument.
```

Can anyone suggest me something or like polyfill for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `fontWeight`, change:

```
text.style.fontStyle = fontStyle
```

to

```
text.style.fontWeight = "bold";
```

**Note:: The `<font>` element has been removed in HTML5 and shouldn't be used anymore. Instead CSS properties should be used.**

Added::
may be you could check if property is supported:: like:

```
if ('fontStyle' in document.body.style) { //returns true if its supported
    text.style.fontStyle = fontStyle;
}
else {
    text.style.fontWeight = fontStyle;
}
```

Comment: Okay that worked. Can I use some polyfills to set this ?

Comment: @user3725375 check the updated answer, but still using CSS would be much better option

Comment: if ('fontStyle' in document.body.style) returns true in iE8